# why my calendarView is not showing when clicking next button in fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

why my calendarView is not showing when clicking next button in fragment?

This is my code regarding to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBsoLYhv3nQ&t=412s barber booking app

```
public class BookingStep3Fragment extends Fragment implements ITimeSlotLoadListener {

    //variable
    DocumentReference staffDoc;
    ITimeSlotLoadListener iTimeSlotLoadListener;
    AlertDialog dialog;

    Unbinder unbinder;
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;
    Calendar selected_date;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_time_slot)
    RecyclerView recycler_time_slot;
    @BindView(R.id.calendarView)
    HorizontalCalendarView calendarView;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;

    BroadcastReceiver displayTimeSlot = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.add(Calendar.DATE, 0 ); //current date
            loadAvailableTimeSlotOfStaff(Common.currentStaff.getStaffId(),
                    simpleDateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
        }
    };

    private void loadAvailableTimeSlotOfStaff(String staffId, final String bookDate) {
        dialog.show();

        // /AllServices/Electrical/Partners/J2lvucvaPWWoFONIyIqj/Staff/kdxNP8WYR0rwYRJUpFct
        staffDoc = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("AllServices")
                .document(Common.service)
                .collection("Partners")
                .document(Common.currentPartner.getPartnerId())
                .collection("Staff")
                .document(Common.currentStaff.getStaffId());

        staffDoc.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) //if staff is available
                    {
                        //get information of booking
                        //if not, return empty
                        CollectionReference date = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                .collection("AllServices")
                                .document(Common.service)
                                .collection("Partners")
                                .document(Common.currentPartner.getPartnerId())
                                .collection("Staff")
                                .document(Common.currentStaff.getStaffId())
                                .collection(bookDate);

                        date.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                                    if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()) //if no appointment
                                        iTimeSlotLoadListener.onTimeSlotLoadEmpty();
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //if have
                                        List<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document:task.getResult())
                                            timeSlots.add(document.toObject(TimeSlot.class));
                                        iTimeSlotLoadListener.onTimeSlotLoadSuccess(timeSlots);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                iTimeSlotLoadListener.onTimeSlotLoadFailed(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    static BookingStep3Fragment instance;

    public static BookingStep3Fragment getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new BookingStep3Fragment();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        iTimeSlotLoadListener = this;

        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());
        localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(displayTimeSlot, new IntentFilter(Common.KEY_DISPLAY_TIME_SLOT));

        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");

        dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(getContext()).setCancelable(false).build();

        selected_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        selected_date.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(displayTimeSlot);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking_step_three,container,false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        init(itemView);



        return itemView;
    }

    private void init(View itemView) {
        recycler_time_slot.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        recycler_time_slot.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycler_time_slot.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(8));

        //calendar
        Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 2); // 2 days left

        HorizontalCalendar horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(itemView, R.id.calendarView)
                .range(startDate,endDate)
                .datesNumberOnScreen(1)
                .mode(HorizontalCalendar.Mode.DAYS)
                .defaultSelectedDate(startDate)
                .build();
        horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(new HorizontalCalendarListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(Calendar date, int pos) {
                if(selected_date.getTimeInMillis() != date.getTimeInMillis())
                {
                    selected_date = date;

                    loadAvailableTimeSlotOfStaff(Common.currentStaff.getStaffId(),
                            simpleDateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSlotLoadSuccess(List<TimeSlot> timeSlotList) {
        MyTimeSlotAdapter adapter = new MyTimeSlotAdapter(getContext(), timeSlotList);
        recycler_time_slot.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSlotLoadFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        dialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSlotLoadEmpty() {
        MyTimeSlotAdapter adapter = new MyTimeSlotAdapter(getContext());
        recycler_time_slot.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Here's the error that shows up

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.idev.speed_mservices.Model.Partner.getPartnerId()' on a null object reference
        at com.idev.speed_mservices.Fragments.BookingStep3Fragment.loadAvailableTimeSlotOfStaff(BookingStep3Fragment.java:86)
        at com.idev.speed_mservices.Fragments.BookingStep3Fragment.access$000(BookingStep3Fragment.java:52)
        at com.idev.speed_mservices.Fragments.BookingStep3Fragment$1.onReceive(BookingStep3Fragment.java:74)
```

Comment: in loadAvailableTimeSlotOfStaff method check when calling getPartnerId() method.you are calling getPartnerId() at a null object.

Comment: On which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please also respond with @AlexMamo